# Can't select node with XmlDocument.select node

Tags: node.js, xml, vb.net, xpath

I tried to use XmlDocument.select to get value of node in below xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cqresponse xmlns="http://ibm.com/rational/clearquest/web/v7.1">
  <displayname>hello world</displayname>
  <fields>
    <field>
      <fieldname>Defect_details_linenumber</fieldname>
      <datatype>MULTILINE_STRING</datatype>
      <value><![CDATA[["aaa"]]]></value>
    </field>
    <field>
      <fieldname>Defect_detailsAf_artefs</fieldname>
      <datatype>MULTILINE_STRING</datatype>
      <value><![CDATA[["bbb"]]]></value>
    </field>
  </fields>
</cqresponse>
```

with this code

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click     
    Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load("Temp_File.xml")
    Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList
    Dim root As XmlNode = doc.DocumentElement
    nodeList = root.SelectNodes("descendant::fields[field/fieldname='Defect_detailsAf_artefs']")

    Debug.Print(nodeList.Count)
    Debug.Print(nodeList(0).InnerText)
End Sub
```

But nodelist.count always return 0. I think it can't find node "Defect_details_linenumber". Could you please help me to point is there something wrong in xPath "descendant::fields[field/fieldname='Defect_detailsAf_artefs']" or something wrong in code

I tried with xpath ""descendant::fields" but i got the same problem nodelist.count still return 0

**SOLVED**

Node can't be selected because it's lack of namespace. Code will fine with me if we change to like this

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click     
    Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load("Temp_File.xml")

    'Add namespace for xml here
    Dim ns As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
    ns.AddNamespace("ibm", "http://ibm.com/rational/clearquest/web/v7.1")

    'Get root node: node "cqresponse"
    Dim root As XmlNode = doc.DocumentElement
    'Get node which have child node fieldname = 'Defect_details_linenumber'
    Dim node As XmlNode = root.SelectSingleNode("descendant::ibm:fields/ibm:field[ibm:fieldname='Defect_detailsAf_artefs']/ibm:value", ns)

    Debug.Print(node.InnerText) 'it will show "bbb"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the XML has *default namespace* declared at the root. This means all elements without prefix in that XML document are in the namespace `http://ibm.com/rational/clearquest/web/v7.1`. To be able to select element in namespace using XPath you need to define a prefix that references that namespace, and modify the XPath to use that prefix, for example :

```
....
Dim nsManager As New XmlNamespaceManager(New NameTable())
nsManager.AddNamespace("d", "http://ibm.com/rational/clearquest/web/v7.1")
nodeList = root.SelectNodes("//d:fields[d:field/d:fieldname='Defect_detailsAf_artefs']", nsManager)
```

Comment: Hi har07, I have just found solution which the same with your answer =)) However, your question is exactly way, it need a namespace to select. I will vote for this answer. Thanks you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Imports <xmlns="http://ibm.com/rational/clearquest/web/v7.1">

Sub Test()
    Dim xml =
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <cqresponse xmlns="http://ibm.com/rational/clearquest/web/v7.1">
            <displayname>hello world</displayname>
            <fields>
                <field>
                    <fieldname>Defect_details_linenumber</fieldname>
                    <datatype>MULTILINE_STRING</datatype>
                    <value><![CDATA[["aaa"]]]></value>
                </field>
                <field>
                    <fieldname>Defect_detailsAf_artefs</fieldname>
                    <datatype>MULTILINE_STRING</datatype>
                    <value><![CDATA[["bbb"]]]></value>
                </field>
            </fields>
        </cqresponse>

    Dim fields = xml...<field>.Where(Function(f) f.<fieldname>.Value = "Defect_detailsAf_artefs")
    fields.ToList().ForEach(Sub(f) Console.WriteLine(f.ToString()))
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi JohnyL, Is xml...<field> can replace with Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()?

Comment: I just would like ask more about Is this way better than select node ? And why I can't use select node to find node ?

Comment: @Bruce You're just using another set of object which manipulate XML. I'm using [XElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement) (more specifically, [XDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument)) from System.Xml.Linq. Moreover, I use here a unique feature which exists only in VB.NET - [XML Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/xml/xml-literals-overview). The three dots `...` mean selecting every element with defined name no matter how deep it is.

Comment: Hi john, I finally found the solution for it, I am really appreciate your answer and many thanks for your help

Comment: @Bruce Is this some another solution? If it is, then reply to your answer and post your solution there.

Comment: Yes, I put final solution below my question. I hope someone will easily find it when they get the same problem like me :) once again Many thanks for your idea and attemp to help